# WebSocket with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, laravel-5

I'm doing a aplication in Laravel 5.2 that uses websockets. For the websocket connection I'm using [HoaServer](https://github.com/hoaproject/Websocket), wich works very well.

The bad part is, I do not know how to make this server as a controller, or at least have acess to my models, right now I'm using a separeted PDO connection to make the DB querys.

Someone knows if it is possible to make this server as a controller or at least have acess to the database throught laravel models?

My server right now:

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php');

$PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=DBNAME', "USER", "PASS");

$websocket = new Hoa\Websocket\Server(new Hoa\Socket\Server('ws://'.$ip.':'.$porta));

$websocket->on('open', function (Hoa\Event\Bucket $bucket) {
    return;
});

$websocket->on('message', function (Hoa\Event\Bucket $bucket) {
    return;
});

$websocket->on('close', function (Hoa\Event\Bucket $bucket) {
    return;
});

$websocket->run();
```

The closest that I fond was to fire an [laravel event](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/hoawebsocket-with-laravel-5-projects-push-notifications?page=1), that I do not know how. :/

```
//Socket server message event
$server->on('message', function() {
     //Fire your Laravel Event here
});
```

Comment: have you tried to use console? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan

Comment: If you mean "make:controller", yep. I made a system using Laravel, controllers, models and view. The problem is that I do not know how to make new Hoa\Websocket\Server() works inside a controller ^^"

Comment: No, i mean add your code to console using make:console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that what you should do is to create a console command.

```
php artisan make:console StartSocketServer  --command=socket:start
```

and then you edit the generated class as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class StartSocketServer extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'socket:start';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'start the socket server';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $websocket = new Hoa\Websocket\Server(new Hoa\Socket\Server('ws://'.$ip.':'.$porta));

        $websocket->on('open', function (Hoa\Event\Bucket $bucket) {
          return;
        });

        $websocket->on('message', function (Hoa\Event\Bucket $bucket) {
          return;
        });

        $websocket->on('close', function (Hoa\Event\Bucket $bucket) {
          return;
        });

        $websocket->run();
    }
}
```

Finally after registering the command in `App\Console\Kernel` you can run `php artisan socket:start` from your terminal.

I never used HoaServer , But i think this should work.