# Laravel 5.2 run command as daemon/forever

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, daemon

Once I have a command method, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245561/websocket-with-laravel-5-2/38335109#38335109), it is possible to keep that commad running forever?

So far I have an ajax that calls for

```
\Artisan::queue('socket:start');
```

'socket:start' is my command.

That does work, but only for 30 seconds. After that my process dies.

I tried to run as daemon process, [as laravel documentation says](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#daemon-queue-listener) but no luck.

How can I give the user the option to run my command, and keep it alive in background forever?

Comment: Have you checked the logs from the process?

Comment: Nop. Where do I find those? In config/queue.php there is no location for a log. Just something about a 'failed_jobs' table, that I do not have in my DB ^^"

Comment: I mean your socket server... This is just the command that launches it. What do the socket servers logs say?

Comment: The server is ok. When I run it in the console(php artisan socket:start) works fine, and runs 'forever'. The problem seems to be that I'm calling \Artisan::queue('socket:start'); with ajax, and as my command never finish(isn't supoused to) laravel finish it with a timeout

Comment: That's because the CLI version of PHP doesn't have a timeout by default (that I can remember). You can do something like `<?php exec('php artisan socket:start'); ?>` which isn't highly recommended, but an option.

Comment: And that's wat I used @Samsquanch , if you put the exec as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into that problem because the apache version of PHP has a timeout. By default the CLI version does not, so you can use PHP's [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to run the artisan command which should work:

```
exec('php artisan socket:start');
```

As usual, only use this if you know exactly what is going into `exec()`.

Comment: In production, it would be better to set up a software like supervisor to make sure the command runs forever, even in case of events like restart, sudden command failure possibly due to a run time error